# Type mismatch: cannot convert from SpringBootApplication to Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have have recently started to learn SpringBoot. But I am facing with this problem.
Can someone help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance.
**My Code Snippet:**

```
package com.example.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);       
    }

}
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes I found the fix. It was happening because I created a public class with the name "SpringBootApplication". Because of this SpringBootApplication annotation was conflicting with the my own created classes.

Comment: You can add the false code to the question and then answer your question with the right code, that way people with the same problem will know what  to do :)

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Sure i will do the same. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fixed code:  Here I Changes the public class name :

```
package com.example.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAppl {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAppl.class, args);      
    }

}
```